# How to navigate a vertical tab control using AutoIt

Tags: tabcontrol, autoit

I have a tab control in an application that I am automating, but cannot move between the tabs as I would like.

I have looked into the documentation for [ControlCommand](https://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/functions/ControlCommand.htm) which has three commands for a `systabcontrol32`. "CurrentTab", "TabRight", and "TabLeft".

I have a tab control that displays the tabs horizontally, and I am able to use TabRight/TabLeft to navigate accordingly, but I cannot do this in a situation where the tabs are vertical. The "TabRight" and "TabLeft" commands don't do anything. However, I have tried setting focus and using the up/down arrow keys, but it is very difficult to maintain.

I can still use "CurrentTab" on the tab control, and get the proper index, so is there a way to use ControlCommand to select a specific tab index?

I have also read [this thread](https://www.autoitscript.com/forum/topic/55783-need-to-select-certain-tab-in-systabcontrol32/), but none of the *GUICtrlTab* functions are working for me either. What can I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have been unable to find a function that can do this, but I am able to accomplish this through using the arrow keys.

Once I've determined the tab that I'm on using `ControlCommand("window", "text", "tabControl", "CurrentTab", "")` and compare that to the index of the tab I need to get to, I use the up/down arrow keys accordingly.

I have set constants for the indexes of my tabs, and use the difference in indexes to calculate the number of times I need to move up/down.

A sample of the code would be:

```
$currentTab = ControlCommand($window, $text, $tabControl, "CurrentTab", "")
$tabDifference = $currentTab - $endTabIndex
ControlFocus($window, $text, $tabControl)
If $tabDifference > 0 Then
   For $i = 1 To $tabDifference Step 1
      Send("{UP}")
   Next
ElseIf $tabDifference < 0 Then
   For $i = -1 To $tabDifference Step -1
      Send("{DOWN}")
   Next
EndIf
```

If the tabDifference is 0, then we are on the correct tab. While it's not required, I recommend adding an assert statement to ensure you've ended on the right tab:

```
_Assert($endTabIndex = ControlCommand($window, $text, $tabControl, "CurrentTab", ""))
```